# Add a meta value if admin , editor or any other user have open a post in edit mode

Tags: post-meta

In my application user can publish a custom post from front end . And later admin or capable user can update or delete the post .  What I want to do , is to determine if that post is seen by admin or capable user from a dashboard . A post meta "is_seen" is attached to my post , by default it is false . I want to make it true if admin or capable user open the post in edit mode . In short I want to do something when "Edit" link is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution . If someone click a on "Edit" link or change anything of the post . A new meta field which meta key is "_edit_lock" is added .  Thus we can do something when "Edit" link is clicked by

```
add_action( 'added_post_meta', 'add_custom_field_automatically', 10, 4 );
add_action( 'updated_post_meta', 'add_custom_field_automatically', 10, 4 );
function add_custom_field_automatically( $meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value )
{
    if ( '_edit_lock' == $meta_key ) {
       //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hook into the loading of any admin screen with

```
add_action( 'load-post.php', 'tbdn_post_screen' );

function tbdn_post_screen() {
    // Check here whether you're adding a post or
    // editing a post by seeing if $_GET['action']
    // equals 'edit' then add your meta for post with
    // ID $_GET['post']
}
```

Details of all of the admin screen load- hook values are at https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Admin_Screen_Reference